# Firestore query geohash filtering

Tags: swift, google-cloud-firestore, geohashing

Firestore query question. I have a "geohash" field in my document which I want to filter by. 
I have seen Frank's @puf video about getting circular geohashes on yt. For now I don't care about a circular query yet. 
I have a geohash for a user. And lots of 10 precision geohashes which I want to filter.

```
let userGeohash = "c2b2qd"
documentRef.whereField("geohash", isGreaterThanOrEqualTo: userGeohash)
```

I would expect this query to return any geohashed which a great than the userGeohash. But its won't what is being returned.

```
input = "c2b2qd"
expected output:
"c2b2qdh7rs"
"c2b2qdh2ht"
"c2b2qd3etr"
```

But I get nothing returned..My logic here must be the bottleneck..
[image]

EXAMPLE CODE:

```
docRef.whereField("geohash", isGreaterThanOrEqualTo: "c2b2qdd").getDocuments { (query, error) in
            query?.documents.forEach({ (snapshot) in
                let data = snapshot.data()
                print(data["geohash"] as! String)
            })
        }


// returns the following :
c2b2qddkc3q
c2b2qddkdcm
c2b2qddpydb
c2b2qehqtkg
c2b2qey3dje
c2b2qey4e62
c2b2qey4em1
c2b2qkp7cm0
u1hg7pzxs26


// expected output: 
c2b2qddkc3q
c2b2qddkdcm
c2b2qddpydb
```

I've even tried using "aaaaaaaa" as my filter which also returns all the documents.

Comment: The code looks fine, so the problem is more likely in the data. Please add a screenshot (or the JSON `data()`) of a document that you feel should be returned.

Comment: Hi Frank - Maybe its something to do with the query then, is it possible its just checking for strings equal/large character count length, and its not checking each string value?

Comment: It shouldn't be. You can test, by example for searching `documentRef.whereField("category", isGreaterThanOrEqualTo: "soc")`.

Comment: okay, I'll give this another shot. thanks!

Comment: updated with example code @FrankvanPuffelen

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You seem to misunderstand Firebase queries. Your query returns an open ended range:

```
docRef.whereField("geohash", isGreaterThanOrEqualTo: "c2b2qdd")
```

Specifically, this query opens the index on `geohash`, which is ordered lexicographically, it find the first entry that starts with `c2b2qdd` (or larger), and then returns all results from that point on. So that includes results like `c2b2qehqtkg`, since they are *greater or equal than*.

If you want to emulate a *start with* type operation, you need to use a closed range query, which includes an end condition of the range too.

```
docRef.whereField("geohash", isGreaterThanOrEqualTo: "c2b2qdd")
      .whereField("geohash", isLessThan: "c2b2qde")
```

This returns all documents that have a `geohash` field that starts with `c2b2qdd`.

Comment: Thanks for clarification! I will mark it once tested.

Comment: Thanks again Frank, that does it. Its not too accurate, but well enough for my use case

Comment: docRef.whereField("geohash", isGreaterThanOrEqualTo: "abcd")
            .whereField("geohash", isLessThan: "abcd~")

Which returns everything in a 20k block. THANKS